# Hide several HTML elements and show them or append them to a separate section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sorry for the long question in advance.  However, I seriously appreciate anyone who is willing to help here...

I have a form where users select options and then click "Generate Text" and a note is generated for their situation. This one particular note that I'm working on is complex and has 7 different ways in which it could be written.

With that said.  What I want to do is have the user select from a drop down list (yes, I know it's not the best choice, but I've been backed in a corner due to consistent user experience requirements).  Based on the option that the user selects, I want a different selection of user inputs to show up inline (ideally) with the "base" note.   Here is an idea of the base note:

```
<div class="note" id="504">
        <p class="item" id="p504">
          <input type="radio" checked>
          This is the beginning of the note
          <select id="partSelect">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Option 1 ">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2 ">Option 2</option>
            <option value="Option 3 ">Option 3</option>
            <option value="Option 4 ">Option 4</option>
            <option value="Option 5 ">Option 5</option>
            <option value="Option 6 ">Option 6</option>
            <option value="Option 7 ">Option 7</option>
          </select></p>
```

Notice that there are several spaces in the value.  That's because the way the JS is written,  it'll pick up the value of the select in the text of the note (I'm removing some proprietary information).

Previously, I've used a `switch()` statement based on the value of the drop down and then big blocks of code that will hide and show sections. Example:

```
    $("#part1").css("display","none");  
    $("#part2").css("display","inline");
    $("#part3").css("display","none");
    $("#part4").css("display","none");
    $("#part5").css("display","none");
    $("#part6").css("display","none");
    $("#part7").css("display","none");
```

I would like to not do that anymore.  However, my attempts at doing things like:

```
    $(".part").css("display","none");
    $("#part1").css("display","inline");
```

have not worked.

Ideally, I would like to find the contents of a `div` and apply those contents to the end of the base  note so that the user just experiences clicking through a dropdown box and the end of that note changes dependent on the option selected.

Does anyone have the ability to teach me something that I can do??

Comment: The `$(".part").css("display","none"); $("#part1").css("display","inline");` should work.  Can you add the code that you used to attach the event to the `select`.

Comment: it was a .change() event handler... and it *did* work, but I'm trying to find a more elegant solution versus.  Reason:  in the future I might have a dropdown with 13 different values which will mean that I will have 169 different `.css("display","none");` statements.

Comment: The `$(".part").css("display","none");` is all you need.  Check the console to see if there are errors.

Comment: my bad, I didn't see the class/ID combo.. I thought you were looking at from the idea of hiding each separate ID and then displaying each separate ID.  yeah, I don't know why it wasn't working. But again, I'm still trying to find a more elegant solution.  I like @gyre's response.  However, sometimes that will work (depending on the many different forms that we have available) and sometimes it won't work.  The way the notes are collected differs between the different forms.

Comment: You'll have to trace the javascript for the case that don't work because you won't have something simpler than `$(".part").css("display","none");` or `$(".part").hide();`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `value` of each option to store the `id` of the element you want to show. Then, you can use `$('#' + this.value)` inside your `change` event handler to select the element to be shown. Also, lift your DOM query to `$('.part')` out of all event handlers so it is not run multiple times unnecessarily. You can use `.show()` and `.hide()` to control whether elements display, too, instead of `.css()`.

**Edit:** You may not need `.show()` and `.hide()` if you switch the nodes with the variable content between an inline visible area and a hidden block area. See updated example below:

```js
var parts = $('.part')
var content = $('#selected-content')
var templates = $('#hidden-area')

$('#partSelect').change(function () {
  content.contents().appendTo(templates)
  $('#' + this.value, templates).appendTo(content)
})
```

```css
#hidden-area {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note" id="504">
  <p class="item" id="p504">
    <input type="radio" checked/>
    This is the beginning of the note
    <select id="partSelect">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="part1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="part2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="part3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="part4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="part5">Option 5</option>
      <option value="part6">Option 6</option>
      <option value="part7">Option 7</option>
    </select>
    <span id="selected-content"></span>
  </p>


<p id="hidden-area">
  <span class="part" id="part1">Part 1</span>
  <span class="part" id="part2">Part 2</span>
  <span class="part" id="part3">Part 3</span>
  <span class="part" id="part4">Part 4</span>
  <span class="part" id="part5">Part 5</span>
  <span class="part" id="part6">Part 6</span>
  <span class="part" id="part7">Part 7</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i like this.  This will save me a lot of time in the future with other updates.  I really appreciate it.  

I have a question:  

Assuming that each part is actually a `div` with a whole bunch of other inputs in there--instead of showing the items how about doing a little something like this??

       ` var parts = $(".part");
 parts.hide();
 $("#partSelect").change(function() {
  parts.hide();
  $("#" + this.value).contents().appendTo($("#p504"));
 });`

Basically, I'm trying to get the contents of that div to be applied -inline with that note.

Comment: I just got out of a meeting and ran this code.  It works but when the note is collected it only picks up the first input that it find. for example  part1's span: `<span class="part" id="part1"><input type="text" value="something here"><select class="lookup"></select></span>`.... when the text generator pulls the text from the span "selected-content", it will only pull "something here" versus the value of the select.  If I remove the first input, it will pull the value from the other drop down.  Any ideas??

Comment: Could you edit your question to include that entire example you were trying, as a runnable snippet, and document the desired behavior a little more clearly? Then I might be able to help.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I don't think that I can because you'll need to know exactly how the note is collected and my predecessor overly complicated their code.  it's  much more simple on another one of our forms.. but this one makes your code break for the slightest little things... but like I said, I will try to show you.  give me a few.  thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work.  I copied over as much of the code as possible and the button wouldn't work like it does in my document.  sorry. I appreciate all your help anyway.